# Export events URL in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, calendar

I want to get the webcal URL for the export events page using Facebook API,

```
url = webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=YYYY&key=XXXXX
```

I want to know how to get the key=XXXXX part.

Which I can easily add to the Google calendar to display all of my Facebook events there.

Comment: Hey! can you got solution?

Answer (score -1):

Actually if you want to get the link for your account, just login to facebook and do following:

Go to **events** (in left menu) -> In front of event (title) there are two buttons: + Create event and a search button.
If you click search button, the last item is export.
If you click export you'll get the link for your account.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the question was to get the link programmatically and not manually.